# how to update a specific field(column) of a row by that row's autoincrement value with some prefix in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql-update

i have below table

```
  it_id     item_id     item_name   
    1   ite_1            shirt
    2   ite_10           pant
    3   ite_11           socks
    4   ite_12           shoes
    5   ite_13            belt
```

now i need to change item_id with with `ite_(value of it_id of that row)`

means `if it_id=x then item_id should be ite_x` and so on...

what will b sql query for that??

#### UPDATE ###

if i want to change `it_id` with a prefix means 
new `it_id=ite_x where x is it's(it_id's) previous value`(1,2,3,4,5 etc....) and it_id is not an auto increment field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
update table_name SET item_id=CONCAT('ite_', id)
```

SORRY your column id it_id, so it should be (Not Sure Though)

```
update table_name SET item_id=CONCAT('ite_', it_id)
```

I think you can do it with follwing steps
1] Change datatype of it_id to VARCHAR 
2] your query is

```
update table_name SET it_id=CONCAT('ite_', it_id)
```

Comment: Thank you Salil. is there any method in which we can use previous value of that field with new value. means if i want to add ite_x in each it_id field?( when it_id is not auto increment)

Comment: sorry i didn't get it? ple explain it in detail or give an example.