# MySQL question: How to insert unique non-integer employee ids?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I want to insert data into a table like the following:

```
emp_id          emp_data
----------------------------
emp001          Amit
emp002          Ajit
emp003          Arijit
```

Over here all the emp_id data should be unique but should follow the pattern of emp***. Please help. I am a novice in db.

Comment: Does emp_id have to be a string? Using an auto_increment integer as the primary key would be simpler, more efficient.

Comment: This is answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3245429/autoincrement-of-table-id-using-string-combination-in-database-automatically

Comment: notice that unless you have a very(very) good reason to do that, you should not do such a thing.

Comment: Why did you tag this question with php? Do you want to use php to generate the emp_id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
create table employee (
  empnum varchar(10) primary key
, empname varchar(60)
);

insert into employee values ('emp001', 'Employee 1');
insert into employee values ('emp002', 'Employee 2');
insert into employee values ('100emp', 'Employee 3');
```

Answer (score 0):

once i asked [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2911632/how-to-update-a-specific-fieldcolumn-of-a-row-by-that-rows-autoincrement-value), but later i realized that , this is not good idea to add prefix/suffix with auto increment field

better u change your table structure

```
emp_id    emp_uniq_id    emp_data
----------------------------------
1         emp001          Amit
2         emp002          Ajit
3         emp003          Arijit
```

and u can use below query

```
mysql_query("UPDATE table_name SET emp_uniq_id=CONCAT('emp', ".str_pad(emp_id,3,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT).") )";
```

Answer (score 0):

If the `emp` prefix is going to remain constant it makes more sense to store it your application logic and prepending it when fetching columns from the database.

Either way, you're only going to be able to `AUTO_INCREMENT` numeric columns.

That having been said, you can group your primary key like so:

```
CREATE TABLE animals (
    grp ENUM('fish','mammal','bird') NOT NULL,
    id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (grp,id)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;

INSERT INTO animals (grp,name) VALUES
    ('mammal','dog'),('mammal','cat'),
    ('bird','penguin'),('fish','lax'),('mammal','whale'),
    ('bird','ostrich');

SELECT * FROM animals ORDER BY grp,id;
```

The output of the select would be:

```
+--------+----+---------+
| grp    | id | name    |
+--------+----+---------+
| fish   |  1 | lax     |
| mammal |  1 | dog     |
| mammal |  2 | cat     |
| mammal |  3 | whale   |
| bird   |  1 | penguin |
| bird   |  2 | ostrich |
+--------+----+---------+
```

Cribbed from the online docs: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html